# How do I check if this is a valid density function without an interval?

Tags: probability, functions, random-variables

I saw this question in an exam and I am not sure how to approach it.

I am not given an interval in which to evaluate the joint function, it just tells me that I need to check if it is a valid density function using one of its most important properties.
$$f_x,_y(x,y) = u(x) * u(y) * \lambda_1\lambda_2exp(-(\lambda_1x+\lambda_2y))$$

Then, it tell me to get the marginal density function of X and Y.

Can anyone give me a hint?

Comment: What is $u(x)$?  The indicator function that equals $1$ if $x>0$ and $0$ otherwise?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that $u(x)$ is the characteristic function of $\mathbb{R}^+$, you can assume that you are asked to verify that $f$ is a correct pdf on $\mathbb{R}^2$, as it is a rather common practice to give a pdf without a domain of definition but an indicator function.

Then, you can see that your f is actually the product of two well known distributions (that I'll let you find), and using a property that goes something like *"The pdf of two _________ events is equal to the product of each of these events' pdf"* (once again, blank left for you to complete), you can deduce that this is actually a correct pdf.